# What's the word for using a general argument that upon inspection does not apply?

Tags: logic

Examples, some are ridiculous:
Someone refuses to buy a lab grown diamond because 'all diamonds are blood diamonds'.

We cannot buy a sports car because 'the trunks of sports cars are too small', even though this sports car has a larger than average trunk.

Someone refuses to drink wine because 'wine comes from France', even though this particular wine is from Chile.

Comment: [*Specious*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specious) is the adjective that comes to mind, but there may be a better one.

Comment: talking a lot of baloney?

Comment: There are possible duplicates, eg [Does this logical fallacy have a name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/does-this-logical-fallacy-have-a-name/16155#16155), but none give the general question.

Comment: I would accept the answer a "specious argument" from @Mick

Comment: @Edwin has nailed it. All of the examples that you have provided are *red herrings*, although they are, of course, also *specious*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yeah, this question is more generically worded and hence would make a good canonical Q&A. I've VTC your linked question as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the **association fallacy**.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy):

> An association fallacy is an informal inductive fallacy of the
>   hasty-generalization or red-herring type and which asserts, by
>   irrelevant association and often by appeal to emotion, that qualities
>   of one thing are inherently qualities of another.
>
> Two types of association fallacies are sometimes referred to as guilt
>   by association and honor by association.

Comment: I'd like to see more answers before I accept because I think that "by irrelevant association and often by appeal to emotion" do not apply in this case.

Comment: 'Irrelevant association' is the nub of your question. 'Often' allows for 'not always'.

Comment: Who decides an association is irrelevant? Maybe the wine drinker won't drink because wine is associated with France and they hate all things French. The same for diamonds, by buying any diamond it shows there is a market for diamonds, thus feeding a demand for blood diamonds.

Comment: _You_ specified 'a general argument that upon inspection does not apply'. That means that _someone_ has to be deciding that the association is irrelevant (here, pragmatics means that 'irrelevant to the argument' must be understood) / misleading.