# Expression or cognitive error in assuming one person's fault on a community

Tags: expressions, psychology

Is there a term in psychology or English language to express the cognitive error in  extrapolating one person's fault on the entire community?

Example:

A: Doctor A is arrested for unethical medical practices.
B: All doctors are like that.

A: Teacher X works just for the money.
B: No teacher is committed to their work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this logical fallacy have a name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/does-this-logical-fallacy-have-a-name): It's the 'association fallacy', 'guilt by association', 'tarring [all] people with the same brush', stereotyping,  'Hitler ate Sugar(!)' ... More generally, ['affirming the consequent'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418353/whats-the-word-for-using-a-general-argument-that-upon-inspection-does-not-apply).

Answer (score 1):

Formally,

- a **[faulty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization)** is a conclusion made about all or many instances of a phenomenon, that has been reached on the basis of one or a few instances of that phenomenon.

Informally,

- a **[stereotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype)** is an over-generalized belief about a particular category of people.